# HttpWebResponse return The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#

i want to get HTML output in

http://www.belmondo.si/turisticna-ponudba/pocitnice/kratkirezultati?cid=ID&cityid=DPS&izhid=&trajanjeid=&oskrbaid=&kategorijaid=&ooseb=2&otrok=0&lasten=1&prvic=1&rid=0-1&subtemplate=eksotika

but i always get

HTTPWEBRESPONSE The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

I am using HttpWebResponse

```
protected string GetHtmlStringA(string url)
    {
        string sHtml = "";
        HttpWebRequest request;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        Stream stream = null;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        sHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
        if (stream != null) stream.Close();
        if (response != null) response.Close();
        return sHtml;
    }
```

i also try with UserAgent but it is the same

```
req.request=
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073022 Firefox/3.0.13";
```

i can't find any solution on forums or internet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you also need to send an `Accept` header. Sending a request with the following headers will work:

```
request.UserAgent = "Foo";
request.Accept = "*/*";
```

Comment: It seems adding accept header as you entered is necessary. for whom using webclient can do like this: `webClient.Headers.Add("accept", "*/*");`

Comment: Does not help for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass authentication credentials with the web request:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your credentials set correctly.

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

// if we have a proxy set its creds as well
if( request.Proxy != null )
{
   request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}
```

If you need specific credentials you can create them this way

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username", "password");
```

Comment: hmm non of solutions works. I do not hace username and passwd. Why i need username and passwd for reading HTML?